How to divide element's nodes into two parts and apply templates separately when transforming html to xml?
I have the following markup:
<p>
    <span>
        <img id="1286087c-14c9-4678-bfb6-d33fb75300dd"/>
    </span>
    <i>Quantity: </i>250 mg; 150<span>
        <img id="15d9f37c-868f-4cc8-b656-fccdb8017ee9"/>
    </span>; 170<span>
        <img id="15d9f37c-868f-4cc8-b656-fccdb8017ee9"/>
    </span>
</p>


What I need is I need to divide this into 2 parts:

Need to match all child element nodes of p till i child (including i child as well). So, in this case span and i and map it to TypeA element: <TypeA>Quantity<TypeA>

Need to match all text and element nodes which come after i child of p. Then tokenize it with semicolon space and place whatever before semicolon space into TypeB element. In this case output should be <TypeB>250 mg<TypeB> <TypeB>150<TypeB> <TypeB>170<TypeB>
Also, I need make sure that template rules for span work.


Here are the template rules I used:
<xsl:mode name="marker" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="analyze"/>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="i" mode="italic"/>
    <xsl:variable name="markers" as="element(p)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="marker"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$marker" mode="wrap"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p/node()[not(self::i)]" mode="marker">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., ';\s')" mode="analyze-strength"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*:match" mode="analyze-strength">
    <semicolon/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p" mode="wrap">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="semicolon">
        <xsl:element name="TypeB">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="semicolon"/>
<xsl:template match="p/i" mode="italic">
    <xsl:element name="TypeA">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::span"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 


Please edit your question to add the current result and the result you want.

Also the shown result snippets like <TypeA>Quantity<TypeA> (should be <TypeA>Quantity</TypeA>, no?) contain only the plain text, the other elements like span or img seem to be irrelevant for the output. That way it seems like you could simply process the text nodes.

It sounds like you don't care about the element content of the p element, except for wanting to use the i element to split the content of the p element into two strings, consisting of:

the text value of every node up to (and including) the i, and
the text value of the nodes following the i

... and then to further tokenize that second string using the delimiter ; .
If that's the case then something like this will work for you:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="until-i" select="(i/preceding-sibling::node(), i)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="after-i" select="i/following-sibling::node()"/>
      <TypeA><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join($until-i))"/></TypeA>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(string-join($after-i), ';\s')">
        <TypeB><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></TypeB>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
   <TypeA>Quantity:</TypeA>
   <TypeB>250 mg</TypeB>
   <TypeB>150</TypeB>
   <TypeB>170</TypeB>
</p>

